# getting unique value from many dynamic textbox

Tags: php, jquery

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  function some() {
    var name=$('#w').attr('name');
    alert(name);
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
  for($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo"<input type='text' name='$i' id='w' onchange=\"some()\">";
  }
?>
```

here from many textbox if I set value of the 1 textbox the value of that textbox should be obtained. I receive only the value of last textbox

Comment: You want to `alert()` the name of the input that changed?

Comment: I want the id of the textbox which I have inserted

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: how do I get particular textbox value which I have edited or inserted

Comment: I tried everything possible it gives me last name which is 9's value

Comment: The changed setup won't return the last but the first "name"

Comment: just let me know how can I pass the id or name of checkbox I have edited, to the function in js because it either shows first or last index